# Is it possible to Automate web application inside Remote Desktop?

Tags: uiautomation

We are having a scenario like below:

1. Login to the application from local machine
2. Create scenarios inside remote desktop and the url to open RDP will be available in browser which is opened in local.
3. By clicking on hyperlink RDP window will be appeared
4. Enter Password inside RDP window
5. RDP is opened with web application

Is it possible to automate step 1 to step 5?

If Possible which tool will be suitable for this case?

Record and Play back option available?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. Two approaches:

1. Using some screenshot-driven *desktop* automation software. The best known is here is [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/).
2. If you do the **RDP connection inside the web browser** using a tool like [Guacamole](https://guacamole.incubator.apache.org/), you can use the screenshot based [Kantu Web Automation](https://a9t9.com/kantu/web-automation) tool. The advantage of this approach is that everything happens inside a Chrome browser and the solution does not take over your desktop and can be run headless (Sikuli requires an unlocked desktop).

Both options have record & replay features and are free.

Comment: Thanks for the response.. will go through the tools mentioned..

Comment: Whether we need to setup these tools inside each RDP?
If yes RDP is dynamic in my case.. so its not possible to setup tools inside rdp.. Please advice in this case.. Thanks